# Why does the PDF use a different variable than x?

Tags: random-variable, density-function, cumulative-distribution-function

In the below image (from Wikipedia but also found in my text book), I noticed that the variable within the integrand is a "u" rather than the "x" which is found in the CDF function. Why is the function being differentiated with respect to u rather than x? It is my understanding that x is the random variable in question due to the subscript **X** on both the CDF and PDF.

Thanks in advance!

[image: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Formal_definition]

Comment: The variable of integration has no significance when evaluating a definite integral: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446591/why-is-it-considered-incorrect-to-use-the-variable-of-integration-as-a-boundary

Comment: @MossMurderer Is there a reason they don't use x there? I'm not understanding why they would use a different variable.

Comment: (1) they could call it $u$, $s$, $y$, it doesn't matter. (2) They *must* use a different variable than $x$ to integrate over because $x$ is already being used! $x$ is the argument of $F$.

Comment: For example, let $f_t$ denote the number of burglaries on day $t$. Then $F_t = \sum_{i=1}^t f_i$ denotes the total number of burglaries that have occurred from day 1 to day $t$. Notice how $F_t = \sum_{t=1}^t f_t$ is completely non-sensical/ambiguous because you're using $t$ in two different ways.

Comment: Note that $F$ is a function of $x$ and on the RHS $x$ is already playing its role -- [it's the top limit on the integral](https://i.stack.imgur.com/flDn1.png). So for the same reason that if you are summing up to $t$, you don't use $t$ as the index in the sum (you might sum $i=1,...,t$) - otherwise one variable would be doing two different jobs. The $u$ is a 'dummy' which carries no special meaning, it's just a placeholder like $i$ in a sum.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/940640/why-we-use-dummy-variables-in-integral and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111868/cumulative-distribution-function-what-does-t-in-int-exp-t2dt-stand-for

Comment: Thank you all for the help! I get it now. After plugging in the bounds of the integration the "dummy variable" ceases to exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, $X$ is a random variable but $x$ is only a number. By definition of the CDF,
$$ F_X(x) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq x]$$
and to calculate this quantity we need to integrate the PDF of $X$ from $-\infty$ to the value $x$. Since the symbol $x$ is already used for the upper limit of the integral, we need another symbol in the integral. Hence $u$ (or any other symbol) can be used.

If this notation is unfamiliar to you, try this instead
$$ F_X(a) = \mathbb{P}[X \leq a] = \int_{-\infty}^{a}f_X(x)dx$$