# Question about the expression of the CDF for a standard normal distribution

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

[image]

My question is with regards to the second equation.

Why is the term in the integral using the variable y? Shouldn't it be z? Because in the first equation, we have the PDF as a function of z. So to then calculate the area under the PDF, I thought we would then sum up the slices along z (the x axis).

Comment: $y$ is just a placeholder, a dummy. $z$ is the upper limit of the integral, so it can't also be the variable telling us where we are up to in adding up the "bits of probability" on our way from $-\infty$ to $z$, any more than we can say $\sum_{i=1}^i f(i)$ ($i$ can't go from $1$ to $i$, if we want to sum up the bits between $1$ and $i$ we need to have some *other* variable, like $j$ do that). This is covered in several answers on site already, though it's not a stats question as such.

Comment: e.g. see this duplicate https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/362417/why-does-the-pdf-use-a-different-variable-than-x

Comment: @Glen_b That makes complete sense. If we used z as the upper limit of the integral, that means z represents a number. If we also used z as the variable in the function then we won't have a function because z is just a number, so the expression becomes nonsensical. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I believe @Glen_b has answered your question about the use of $y$ in your formula. Here is a little more about standard normal CDFs.

The CDF of a standard normal random variable $Z$, the $\Phi_Z(z)$ of your question, cannot be expressed in closed algebraic form. Of course, it can be closely approximated by numerical integration, as
you suggest. Printed tables of this CDF (with probabilities accurate to four or five places) are widely available---likely in
your probability or statistics textbook.

It is also possible to find a (piecewise) rational function
that approximates this integral very well (accurate up to double
precision arithmetic in most computer programs). This excellent
approximation is implemented in R as `pnorm` (with mean $0$ and
SD $1$ as default. Three examples are shown below. You may want to look
in a printed normal table to see corresponding values there.

```
pnorm(0)
[1] 0.5
pnorm(1)
[1] 0.8413447
pnorm(2)
[1] 0.9772499
```

In the figure below, these are areas under the standard normal density curve to the left of the dark green, maroon, and blue
vertical lines, respectively.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
hdr = "Standard Normal Density"
curve(dnorm(x), -3.5, 3.5, lwd=2, 
       ylab="Density", xlab="z", main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="darkgreen")
 abline(v=1, col="maroon")
 abline(v=2, col="blue")
```

The corresponding inverse CDF (quantile function) is implemented
in R as `qnorm`. This is roughly equivalent to finding the
approximate value of a probability in the body of a printed standard normal CDF table and
looking for its z-score in the margins of the table. [You will get about two-place accuracy.] The following
output shows $a,b,c$ with $P(Z \le a) = 0.975,$ $P(Z \le b) = 0.95,$
$P(Z \le c) = 0.90,$ respectively.

```
qnorm(.975);  qnorm(.95);  qnorm(.90)
[1] 1.959964  # a  (khaki)
[1] 1.644854  # b  (magenta)
[1] 1.281552  # c  (cyan)
```

[image]